# System interrupts causing high CPU usage

Tags: windows-10, drivers, thinkpad, cpu-usage, interrupts

I purchased a Lenovo ThinkPad Helix 2 2-in-1 laptop/tablet second-hand around a month ago, it came with Windows 10 Pro and was working OK for a few weeks but recently I have had a problem with constant CPU usage of about 20-30% when idle. Task Manager is showing **System Interrupts** and **System** as the culprits:

[image: Task Manager]

I decided to reinstall Windows to remove all the preinstalled Lenovo junk and test with the default Windows drivers but it's made no difference.

Testing with LatencyMon I can see ACPI.sys and/or storport.sys are possibly implicated:

[image: ACPI.sys]
[image: storport.sys]

The only thing I am aware I did that could be related was to configure the battery management using Lenovo Vantage to disable charging of both batteries until they are below 80%.